# Scrapy CSV column export

Tags: python, scrapy

I´d like to export data to several columns in csv but I always obtain this kind of file:

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBA4U.png)

I´d like to obtain two columns one "articulo" and another one "price"

My pipelines:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
import csv

class MercadoPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

        def spider_opened(self, spider):
            file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
            self.files[spider] = file 
            self.exporter = CsvItemexporter(file)
            self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['articulo','precio']
            self.exporter.start_exporting()


        def spider_closed(self, spider):
            self.exporter.finish_exporting()
            file = self.files.pop(spider)
            file.closed()

        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            self.exporter.export_item(item)
            return item
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: It's not about your pipeline but spider instead. Something is wrong with your `items`. Please show target page and your spider's code

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for your answer, here you are, I´m going to copy it as an answer of my question because is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from mercado.items import MercadoItem


class MercadoSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'mercado'
item_count = 0
allowed_domain = ['www.autodoc.es']
start_urls = ['https://www.autodoc.es/search?brandNo%5B0%5D=101']

rules = {

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('//span[@class="next"]/a'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('//a[@class="ga-click"]')),
                    callback = 'parse_item', follow = False)
}


def parse_item(self, response):
    ml_item = MercadoItem()

    #info de producto
    ml_item['articulo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]/span/text())').extract()
    ml_item['precio'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/p[2]/text())').extract()
    self.item_count += 1
    if self.item_count > 20:
        raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
    yield ml_item
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the output of your code.
You *are* getting the two csv columns you want, but the program you are using to view the data is not interpreting it correctly.

By default, `CsvItemExporter` uses `,` as the delimiter, and the program seems to expect something else (and possibly even different quoting).
There are two possibilities to solve your problem:

- Change the program's settings so it reads the file correctly
- Change the way `CsvItemExporter` exports data (it will pass any additional keyword arguments to the underlying [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) object)